# Grafana Workspace: ConflictException: Duplicate request for workspace

Tags: terraform, grafana, terraform-provider-aws

trying to create AWS managed Grafana workspace with below specifications.
And getting error when I terraform apply, there is no other grafana resource created in account.

```
resource "aws_grafana_workspace" "grafana_workspace" {
  name                      = "${var.prefix}-grafana"
  description               = "Grafana Workspace for ${var.region}"
  account_access_type       = "CURRENT_ACCOUNT"
  notification_destinations = ["SNS"]
  authentication_providers  = ["AWS_SSO"]
  permission_type           = "SERVICE_MANAGED"
  role_arn                  = "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/${var.prefix}-grafana-role"
  data_sources              = ["PROMETHEUS", "CLOUDWATCH"]
}

resource "aws_grafana_role_association" "grafana_role_association" {
  role         = "ADMIN"
  group_ids    = ["Admins"]
  workspace_id = aws_grafana_workspace.grafana_workspace.id
}


error creating Grafana Workspace: ConflictException: Duplicate request for workspace
│
│   Message_: "Duplicate request for workspace"
│ }
│ 
│   with aws_grafana_workspace.grafana_workspace,

│    1: resource "aws_grafana_workspace" "grafana_workspace" {
```

Comment: Have you tried creating it previously with terraform and it had other errors? Because the documentation says "A resource was in an inconsistent state during an update or a deletion.".

Comment: I have tried to create but I was not able to because of IAM role. For IAM using two layers with pass role. I think issue is it's pretty new service. I was able to create on AWS Console in sandbox account.

Comment: Can you delete anything created with Terraform and re-apply?

Answer (score 1):

We are in contact with aws support and they are aware of this issue, however they have suggested a way we can work around this situation at this time. Always when creating a Grafana workspace, send a different request in the description field, that way the request will be different and we will be successful.
This is just an outline.
We're using a random_id that timestamps and updates a number in the grafana description every time it's recreated.